# Sql dynamic query syntax error

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

This is my sql query

```
"select * from applicant where email =ABC.Com"
```

I want table name,  colum name and value after where clause dynamic in form of variables there.  Can you tell me the right syntax?  I have tried this so far

```
"select * from " tableNameVariable+"where "columnNameVariable+"= "inputedEmailVariable
```

now this query is giving an error near `=inputedEmailVariable`. 
Note : I want to use this string in nodejs function.  Please tell me right syntax?

Comment: "select * from " + tableNameVariable + " where " + columnNameVariable +  " = '" + inputedEmailVariable + "'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
"select * from " + tableNameVariable + " where " + columnNameVariable + " = '" + inputedEmailVariable + "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some `+` operators, and also missing a space before `where`.

```
var sql = "select * from " + tableNameVariable + " where " + columnNameVariable + " = " + inputedEmailVariable
```

You should be very careful if the variables are coming from user input, since this can result in SQL injection. Make sure the variables contain table and column values that they're allowed to access.

And if you're compareing the column with a string, you'll need quotes around the string. But it would be better to use a placeholder at that point, rather than concatenating the variable.

Comment: How to use placeholder?