# Mysqli_query fails to execute and throwing an error

Tags: php, mysqli

I am retrieving data from my table in php. My code is here :

```
<?php 
$con = require('config.php');
?>

<html>
<head><title>Php Practise Web</title></head>
    <body>
        <?php 
            $sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM  customers';
            $customersData = mysqli_query($con,$sqlQuery);
                if(!$customersData){
                    die('Error in retrieving :'.mysqli_connect_error($con));
                    }
                    else{
                 while($dataRow = mysqli_fetch_array($customersData, MYSQLI_NUM)){?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <thead>Customer Name<thead>
                <thead>Customer Email<thead>
                <thead>Customer Username<thead>
                <thead>Customer Age<thead>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $dataRow['c_name']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dataRow['c_email']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dataRow['c_username']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dataRow['c_age']?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php 
                 }
            }
    ?>
    </body>
  </html>
```

but it is throwing an error like this 
Here is my config.php code

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","phppractise");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to Mysql : ".mysqli_connect_errno();
}
else{
    echo "Database Connected";
  }
```

?>

[image]

Actually from very first i am making a connection with my db and then retrieving data from table named  "customers". I am passing connection variable and query variable both in mysqli_query but it's still throwing an error .Please tell me where my code is wrong ?

Comment: post the code found in `config.php`. It returns an integer -- read the error.

Comment: any relation to your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46739498/1415724 - you should edit your question to contain what's in the config.php file.

Comment: I didn't even know `require()` *had* a return value.  But it appears that the return value is an integer.  `mysqli_query()` is expecting a `mysqli` connection object.  Where is that?

Comment: Start by removing `, MYSQLI_NUM`, I don't know why you're using that in relation to what seem to be string values in the loop. Other than that, I don't know what else it could be. If it has relation to your other question using node.js, then that could also be a factor here.

Comment: @David heh, right you are. Odd error though.

Comment: i am using MYSQLI_NUM because i found it on w3schools

Comment: That one, was a first for me @FahadSubzwari rather an odd error. Well, another bit of experience for both you and I, *cheers*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `$con =` from in here:

```
$con = require('config.php');
```

That's why you're getting that error.

Just do:

```
require('config.php');
```

or include the file.

```
include('config.php');
```

That variable is the same as your connection.

To try and explain what is going on here, is that it is most likely looping over the variable assignment in the `require()` and the connection, meaning that it's returning `1` as a boolean (integer) as from the error posted.

- That is my best assumption, which to me makes sense.

Taken from the image of the error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli integer given

In order to use syntax like that (`$con = require('config.php');`), you would need to have used a class/method, and from there, to `return` an instance of it.